# C# MongoDB join collections and include filters

Tags: c#, mongodb, join, .net-core, nosql

started using MongoDB in my .net core app using MongoDB.Driver.
I needed to find a way to join collections and include filters.

Looking on how to join this is what I found -

```
            var query = from c in collection1.AsQueryable()
                        join m in collection2.AsQueryable() on
                 c.ClassTwoId equals m.Id into j
                        select new { c, j };
```

Looking on how to filter this is what I found -

```
            //filters
            FilterDefinitionBuilder<PortalUser> builder = Builders<PortalUser>.Filter;
            List<FilterDefinition<PortalUser>> filters = new List<FilterDefinition<PortalUser>>();
            filters.Add(builder.Eq(PortalUser => PortalUser.IsActive, true));

            var result = portalUserCollection.FindAsync<PortalUser>(builder.And(filters));
```

Couldn't find any way to combine the examples above...
The only way I found to filter an IQueryable was to add a where statement inside the IQueryable, but as the filters are dynamic and decided runtime that means I'll have to do lots of if/else and rebuild the IQueryable every time which sounds nuts...

Anyone know of a way around it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use Where clause.

```
var query = from c in collection1.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Name == "Test")
            join m in collection2.AsQueryable() on
            c.ClassTwoId equals m.Id into j
            select new { c, j };
```

Making it dynamic by adding nuget package System.Linq.Dynamic

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
....
var query = from c in collection1.AsQueryable().Where("Age == 123")
            join m in collection2.AsQueryable() on 
            c.ClassTwoId  equals m.Id into j
            select new { c, j };
```

For more information on the Dynamic queries see documentation on System.Linq.Dynamic (parameters etc.)

Comment: How would you make the where clause dynamic in the example above? thanks!

Comment: I have added an example in my answer. Dynamic queries can be made by making strings or other expressions. See documentation on System.Linq.Dynamic